# How to set the cursor some spaces away from the start in an EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText which allows the user to enter the text from the default starting position. I want to move the cursor from the starting position and set it to some 6 dp away from the starting position. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using padding, to edit text.Hope it works for you :)

```
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
```

Comment: This is working perfectly after doing a ton of search

Answer (score 0):

Add left margin attribute to edit text tag.

Comment: I don't want to move the Edittext. I just want to move the cursor inside the EditText to a different position

Comment: Then as said by Harshal Benake set paddingLeft attribute

Answer (score 0):

check this code snippet

```
// et is my EditText Field
et.setText("Updated Text From another Activity");
int position = et.length();
Editable etext = et.getText();
Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
```

Comment: Can't we set the cursor before the user enters the text? I want the user to enter the text from the cursor position that I have set.